# SQL: partition by / window function with the combination of 2 columns, separated by todays date

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

I am trying to create a materialized-view in postgres, where I sum 2 columns, depending on **todays** date within a window function.

In the below picture there is an example of the query I am trying to achieve:

If today is the '2022-06-06':

- 2022-06-05: 1+2+3+4+5
- 2022-06-06: 1+2+3+4+5+6+107
- 2022-06-07: 1+2+3+4+5+6+107+108

[image]

Here is a sample fiddle with date:

<s>http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/538ea7/1</s> Updated: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bef30/3

Would greatly appreciate any help!

Old Image:

[image]

Edit: Updated Fiddle and Image

Comment: Is the requirement for column A that it displays the sum of actuals up until two days ago?

Comment: Can you explicitly provide a sample input and the corresponding expected output inside your post?

Comment: your image is very confusing as you are mixing userid1 with 2 but your query partions by userid

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I have updated the post, hope it makes things more understandable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you need the following result

```
 user_id | date       | actual | scheduled | sum
 ------: | :--------- | -----: | --------: | --:
       1 | 2022-06-01 |      1 |       100 |   1
       1 | 2022-06-02 |      2 |       101 |   3
       1 | 2022-06-03 |      3 |       103 |   6
       1 | 2022-06-04 |      4 |       104 |  10
       1 | 2022-06-05 |      5 |       105 |  15
       2 | 2022-06-06 |      6 |       106 |  21
       2 | 2022-06-07 |      7 |       107 | 128
       2 | 2022-06-08 |      8 |       108 | 236
       2 | 2022-06-09 |      9 |       109 | 345
       2 | 2022-06-10 |     10 |       110 | 455
```

Then you can use a query like this

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    date,
    actual,
    scheduled,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date <= '2022-06-6' THEN actual ELSE scheduled END)
        OVER (ORDER BY date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM table_1
```

Working [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=1a64a7ccfeae26e1acea6b2795f6efec)

Comment: many thanks for your help to solve this problem, wish you a great day!

Answer (score 1):

I think the function you want is [Cumulative Aggregation](https://app.rasgoml.com/sql?transformName=%22cumulative_agg%22&tableState=%7B%22tables%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22table%22%2C%22columns%22%3A%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22user_id%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22actual%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22number%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22scheduled%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22number%22%7D%2C%7B%22name%22%3A%22beforeafterpartitionid%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%2C%22baseTableName%22%3A%22table%22%2C%22ddl%22%3A%22%22%7D&formState=%7B%22arguments%22%3A%7B%22aggregations%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22agg_dict%22%2C%22aggDict%22%3A%7B%22Column_3%22%3A%7B%22SUM%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22actual%22%3A%7B%22SUM%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22scheduled%22%3A%7B%22SUM%22%3Atrue%7D%7D%7D%2C%22order_by%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A1%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22date%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A1%7D%5D%7D%2C%22direction%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22value%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22backward%22%7D%2C%22group_by%22%3A%7B%22argType%22%3A%22column_list%22%2C%22cols%22%3A%5B%7B%22id%22%3A0%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22user_id%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22user_id%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A0%7D%2C%7B%22id%22%3A4%2C%22columnName%22%3A%22beforeafterpartitionid%22%2C%22displayName%22%3A%22beforeafterpartitionid%22%2C%22dataType%22%3A%22string%22%2C%22dwColumnId%22%3A4%7D%5D%7D%7D%2C%22transformName%22%3A%22cumulative_agg%22%7D), but before doing so you can add a new column Before/After to get it to partition correctly.

Does this do what you expect?

```
WITH CTE_PART AS (
  SELECT 
    user_id, 
    date, 
    actual, 
    scheduled, 
    CASE WHEN date <= '2022-06-06' THEN 'Before' ELSE 'After' END as BeforeAfterPartitionId 
  FROM 
    table_1
), 
CTE_CUMULATIVE AS (
  SELECT 
    *, 
    SUM(actual) OVER(
      PARTITION BY user_id, 
      BeforeAfterPartitionId 
      ORDER BY 
        date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
        AND CURRENT ROW
    ) as actual_sum, 
    SUM(scheduled) OVER(
      PARTITION BY user_id, 
      BeforeAfterPartitionId 
      ORDER BY 
        date ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING 
        AND CURRENT ROW
    ) as sched_sum 
  FROM 
    CTE_PART
), 
CTE_PRIORS AS (
  SELECT 
    user_id, 
    date, 
    SUM(actual_sum) as PRIORS 
  FROM 
    CTE_CUMULATIVE 
  WHERE 
    date = '2022-06-06' 
  GROUP BY 
    user_id, 
    date
) 
SELECT 
  A.user_id, 
  A.date, 
  A.actual, 
  A.scheduled, 
  case when A.beforeafterpartitionId = 'Before' THEN A.actual_sum ELSE A.sched_sum + coalesce(B.PRIORS, 0) END as want 
FROM 
  CTE_CUMULATIVE A 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_PRIORS B ON A.user_id = B.user_id 
  AND A.date >= B.date 
ORDER BY 
  user_id, 
  date;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bef30/14

Comment: Hey @Josh, already, many thanks for your example, I just tried it out with a slightly different dataset/sqlfiddle here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/bef30/1 and it seems that there is on slight issue that for entries after the date, see screenshot here: https://imgur.com/a/fOlAj3U

Comment: @lucbas okay I made an update. not a bulletproof solution but it works for the example data.  But if this is the case. check out the answer #2 which does this WAY more elegantly! The answerer is Alexey

Comment: thanks for your help anyways, wish you a great day!